# Perf analysis on AMD 19h based machine

Tags: profiling, perf, amd-processor

I'm trying to perform perf analysis for an app running on AMD based machine (EPYC 7443) and record specific events (CPU stall events).
Kernel version: 3.10.0-957.el7

I've tried to attach perf to the process running the app using this cmd:
`perf record -p <pid> -e r<event_number>`

But I'm receiving an error: `The r<event_number>:u event is not supported`

I've took the event numbers from "PPR Vol 1 for AMD Family 19h Model 01h B1"

Not sure if it's related but I also tried to run it with events from here and I received the same error message: `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu<cpu_id>/uevent`.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the kernel version I' using.
I run the same command on machine with newer kernel version and it worked.

Comment: That would make sense,  3.10.0-957.el7 [appears](https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1810.00.x86_64/kernel/20181030130226/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/) to be from Nov. 2018.  Even if they did backport new stuff to that ancient 3.10.0 kernel, it probably wasn't new enough for that CPU released in March 2021.  2.5 years is a long time for model-specific support to have been merged into Linux ahead of the release of CPU hardware.  Especially for it to get backported into an old "stable" kernel like that.  Using software much older than your hardware is not a good way to take full advantage of it.